# Query 2 date ranges against the same column in one select statement without using a sub select?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I am creating a report and in this report I need the output from a date range that goes against the date column. I also need another date range that goes against the date column.
so I would have two outputs. my current code looks like this.

```
Select finvdate 
from SalesDollars where finvdate between '1/15/2014' and '04/15/2014'
```

I tried using a sub select but since there are multiple dates it wont work.

Comment: please post sample input and expected output.

Comment: This is the code I tried with a subquery.  select fccompany,fcustno,ftotprice,finvdate, (select fccompany,fcustno,ftotprice,finvdate 
from SalesDollars where finvdate between '6/15/2013' and '01/15/2014' )
from SalesDollars where finvdate between '1/15/2014' and '04/15/2014'
order by finvdate

Comment: the subquery is not logically joined to the outer query, and should only be returning 1 column, and 1 record.

Comment: We do not fully understand what you are asking. Can you write your question in psudocode? Select ( foo filtered to 2013)  as 2013, (foo filtered to 2014) as 2014  from bar when date in some dates in 2014 or date in some dates in 2013

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you mean something like this?

```
SELECT CASE WHEN finvdate BETWEEN '6/15/2013' AND '1/15/2014' THEN finvdate ELSE NULL END AS FirstDate,
CASE WHEN finvdate BETWEEN '1/15/2014' AND '04/15/2014' THEN finvdate ELSE NULL END AS SecondDate,
FROM SalesDollars
```

Comment: no I need 2 columns for my output with this I would still only have 1

Comment: @Turtleman10 Then I'm not sure what you need exactly.  I've updated my answer -- see if that's what you're looking for.

Comment: That is just what I needed. Thank You I didn't even think about using Case.

Answer (score 0):

I am also not 100% clear what you need, but assuming both columns are in the same table:

```
SELECT
  b.col1,
  c.col2
FROM salesDollars a

LEFT JOIN salesDollars b ON
 b.key = a.key
 AND b.col1 BETWEEN date1 AND date2

LEFT JOIN salesDollars c ON
 c.key = a.key
 AND c.col2 BETWEEN date3 AND date4
```